# How is this Karnaugh Map organized?

Tags: logic, digital-logic, karnaugh-map

A K-map generator generated this for me! [Karnaugh Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVJFH.png)

And I`ve been trying to figure out how the values match up with one another. For eg. the value 7 on the table is seemingly identified by 01101 which is not 7, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Imagine it in 3D as 4x4x2 blocks. You need to group them by height also.

Comment: Do you mind explaining in a bit more detail? Or perhaps directing me to some resources that could do the same?

Comment: For 5 variables KMap, check for possible grouping at 2 levels first, then check whether there is any overlapping cells between the 2 levels, which can form new group or extend existing grouping.

Comment: Sure, but I'm still stuck on the part where I'm able to tell a position by its coordinates using that table

Comment: For that table, the left side is the first level and the right side is the second level. Check the first bit at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row and column elements in a K-map don't have a numeric correspondence to the values in a referent cell; they have a *logical* correspondence, where each digit of a cell or column header represents a binary value for a specific proposition. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) for Karnaugh maps provides an excellent reference for how a logical truth table can be broken down into a K-map.

In your original example, it looks like you have five truth values which are combining to produce a single output value: `01101 => 7`.

Think of each binary position in the number as a seperate value rather than an entire number:

```
01101
ABCDE
```

And you can break it down into the following logic:

`If((Not A) and B and C and (not D) and E) then 7.`